# Cosine of a negative number

Tags: python, python-3.x, trigonometry

I want to find the closest point using cosine distance. But what should I do if a value is negative?

```
a = -3
b = 2
math.acos(a / b)
```

This is giving me an error as `a / b` is a negative number. How do I handle this?

Comment: `acos()` or `cos()`?. If it is acos() the argument must be between -1 and 1, in your case it is not so you should get an exception

Answer (score 1):

Your error isn't because it's a negative number. It's because you're taking the arccos of a number that's out of the range -1<=x<=1. Cosine is

```
math.cos(a/b)
```